# How do you get a .Net Maui Map Center Location?

Tags: dictionary, geolocation, location, maui

If a user scrolls the map I'd like to get the location under the center of the map. I know there's the Map.Frame.Center, but that's the center of the map control rendering, not the map location.

If that property is not available is there any information available as to where the user has moved the map to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mymap.VisibleRegion.Center`